# Помогите новичку с реализацией рандомного отображения промокода на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой вот кусок кода:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html><head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">

.clock {margin:0 auto; color:#fff; }

#Date { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:36px; text-align:center; text-shadow:0 0 5px #00c6ff; }

ul {margin:0 auto; padding:0px; list-style:none; text-align:center; }
.promokod_div {text-align:center; }
ul li { display:inline;font-size:3em; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000000; }

#point { position:relative; -moz-animation:mymove 1s ease infinite; -webkit-animation:mymove 1s ease infinite; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; }

@-webkit-keyframes mymove 
{
0% {opacity:1.0; text-shadow:0 0 20px #00c6ff;}
50% {opacity:0; text-shadow:none; }
100% {opacity:1.0; text-shadow:0 0 20px #00c6ff; } 
}

@-moz-keyframes mymove 
{
0% {opacity:1.0; text-shadow:0 0 20px #00c6ff;}
50% {opacity:0; text-shadow:none; }
100% {opacity:1.0; text-shadow:0 0 20px #00c6ff; } 
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">



function start_promo() {

document.getElementById("proc_button").style.display = "none";
var intervalID1 = setInterval( function() {

 // Создаем объект newDate() и извлекаем секунды текущего времени
 var seconds = i++;
    if(seconds == 10) {
    var seconds = 0;
 var promo = '';
 var promotext = '';
    i = 0;
    ni++;
    }
     if(ni >= 6) {
      clearInterval(intervalID1);
        seconds = 6;
  promo = "f9y6d";
  promotext = "Промо-код:";
     }
     
 // Добавляем начальный ноль к значению секунд
 $("#sec").html(seconds);
 $("#promokod").html(promo);
 $("#promotext").html(promotext);
 },100);



var i = 0;
var ni = 0;
var intervalID2 = setInterval( function() {
 // Создаем объект newDate() и извлекаем минуты текущего времени
 var minutes = i++;
    if(minutes == 10) {
    var minutes = 0;
    i = 0;
    ni++;
    }
     if(ni >= 5) {
      clearInterval(intervalID2);
        minutes = 1;
     }
 // Добавляем начальный ноль к значению минут
 $("#min").html(minutes);
}, 80);

}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="curved-vt-2"  style="color: #000; font-size: 30px; position: relative; /*top: 20px;*/" align="center">
 <span style="color: #ff0000;text-shadow: #363535 0px -3px 2px;font-family: cursive;font-weight: 900;">Добро пожаловать!</span>
 <p style="color: #000000;margin-bottom: 0px;font-family: cursive;font-weight: 900;" align="center">Принимайте участие в розыгрыше <br>Вашей персональной скидки </p>
</div>
<div class="clock">
    <ul style="color: black;">
        <li id="do" style="font-size: 1em; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;">до  </li>
        <li id="min" style="color: red;">9</li>
        <li id="sec" style="color: red;">9</li>
        <li id="procent" style="color: red;">%</li>
        <li id="promotext" style="font-size: 1em; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-shadow: none; font-weight: 900;">   </li>
        <li id="promokod" style="color: red;"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="promokod_div">
<button id="proc_button" onclick="start_promo();" style="height: 40px;font-size: 20px;font-family: cursive;font-weight: 900;background-color: #E92D00;color: whitesmoke; border-radius: 6px; border: 1px solid #a82000;">Получить промо-код</button>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Нужно сделать так чтоб при нажатии на кнопку "получить промокод" выводились рандомно % скидки и различные промокоды привязанеые к этим процентам.

Пока выводится только одно значение статически "до 16 % Промо-код: f9y6d"

Comment: хм, на java или javascript таки?

Comment: на javascript .Будет использоваться на сайте.

Comment: Это конечно мб и оффтоп, но разве это не должно происходить со стороны сервера? Иначе я смогу сколь угодно кодов себе наспамить так. Я бы предложил решение - просто генерировать коды со скидкой на стороне сервера, и значения соответственно вставлять вместо `promo` и суммы скидки.

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/wxhboLqu/ (открой консоль, сумма цифр всегда равна максимальной скидке - 16)

```
 function getcode(max_sale)
{
var sale = Math.floor(Math.random()) * max_sale;

var code = 'S';

var a = Math.floor(Math.random()+1)*4
var b = Math.floor(Math.random()+1)*6
var c = max_sale-(a+b);
var d = c-Math.floor(Math.random()*c/2);
var e = max_sale-a-b-d;

code = code + String(a) + String(b) + String(d) +   String(e);

return code;
}
```

Сумма цифр кода равна максимальной скидке. (аргумент max_sale). Можно добавить еще буквы, по такому же принципу.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно рандомно , то вам стоит делать все через random(). Его можно умножать/делить, брать разные цифры с разных позиций. Например для набора кодов из 10 штук вполне сойдет такой "рандом"

```
function randomInteger(min, max) {
    var rand = min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min);
    rand = Math.floor(rand);
    return rand;
  }
```

Взято [отсюда](https://learn.javascript.ru/task/random-int-min-max)

А вот как привязать к купонам и значениям - тут уже на ваше усмотрение. Лучше конечно сделать массив элементов mass[i] = "NameOfCoupon" где i - это процент скидки, а NameOfCoupon - код купона. Создав такой массив, можно при помощи рандома выше получать значения.

P.S. Необязательно массив делать по порядку т.е. 1% 2% и т.п. Можно просто сделать массив с *выборочными* элементами, например mass[10],mass[20]. Для пустых элементов вернет undefined, на что требуется написать "затычку" или перенаправление.